# string replace breaks on space in C++

Tags: c++

If I input "we are going to have fun in school" when executing the following code, it seems to break after the first word and only prints "W3". Does anyone know what I did wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
  {
  string s;
  cout << "Invoer: ";
  cin >> s;

  replace( s.begin(), s.end(), 'e', '3' );
  replace( s.begin(), s.end(), 'o', '0' );
  replace( s.begin(), s.end(), 't', '7' );
  replace( s.begin(), s.end(), 'l', '1' );
  transform( s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), ::toupper);

  cout << s << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is the default behaviour for `std::cin`, you may consider using `std::getline` instead.

Comment: Also, to avoid the risk of undefined behavior, you need to make sure the `char`'s from the string are converted to `unsigned char` before feeding them to `toupper` (which you should be referring to as `std::toupper`, after properly including `cctype`).

Comment: @DenisSheremet -- it's not the behavior of `std::cin`. It's the behavior of `operator>>` on any input stream. It stops reading when it encounters training whitespace.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `getline` instead of `cin >> s` to grab the whole line, otherwise it stops at whitespace:

```
getline(cin, s);
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/uiQnQdBZoCcjSjBf)

Comment: @NicovanBentum If this solves your problem please don't forget to accept!